# Unable to upgrade to Endpoints Version 2

Tags: java, google-cloud-endpoints

I followed the instructions on this page exactly:
https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/legacy/v1/java/migrating

And now when I attempt to deploy the app, it hangs on "Updating Services", and eventually the process crashes.
When I look at the error log on the Google Cloud Console, I see two similar errors:
1)

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.api.server.spi.config.AnnotationBoolean cannot be cast to com.google.api.server.spi.config.AnnotationBoolean
at com.google.api.server.spi.config.annotationreader.ApiConfigAnnotationReader.readApi (ApiConfigAnnotationReader.java:173)
at com.google.api.server.spi.config.annotationreader.ApiConfigAnnotationReader.readEndpointClass (ApiConfigAnnotationReader.java:151)
at com.google.api.server.spi.config.annotationreader.ApiConfigAnnotationReader.loadEndpointClass (ApiConfigAnnotationReader.java:50)
at com.google.api.server.spi.config.ApiConfigLoader.loadConfiguration (ApiConfigLoader.java:71)
at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService.registerService (SystemService.java:148)
at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.registerService (SystemServiceServlet.java:179)
at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.createSystemService (SystemServiceServlet.java:172)
at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.createSystemService (SystemServiceServlet.java:136)
at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.init (SystemServiceServlet.java:59)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet (ServletHolder.java:440)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet (ServletHolder.java:339)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle (ServletHolder.java:487)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter (ServletHandler.java:1166)
at com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter.doFilter (ObjectifyFilter.java:48)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter (ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter (ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter (ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter (SaveSessionFilter.java:37)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter (ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter (JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:60)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter (ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter (TransactionCleanupFilter.java:48)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter (ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle (ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle (SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle (SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle (ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle (WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle (AppVersionHandlerMap.java:257)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle (HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle (Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest (HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete (HttpConnection.java:923)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable (RpcRequestParser.java:76)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle (HttpConnection.java:404)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest (JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:146)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchServletRequest (JavaRuntime.java:680)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchRequest (JavaRuntime.java:642)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run (JavaRuntime.java:612)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext (TraceContext.java:454)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run (TraceContext.java:461)
at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext (CurrentContext.java:297)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref (TraceContext.java:320)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext (TraceContext.java:312)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run (TraceContext.java:458)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run (ThreadGroupPool.java:274)
at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:745)
```

2)

```
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.api.server.spi.config.AnnotationBoolean cannot be cast to com.google.api.server.spi.config.AnnotationBoolean
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.makeUnavailable (ServletHolder.java:415)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet (ServletHolder.java:458)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet (ServletHolder.java:339)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle (ServletHolder.java:487)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter (ServletHandler.java:1166)
at com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter.doFilter (ObjectifyFilter.java:48)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter (ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter (ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter (ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter (SaveSessionFilter.java:37)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter (ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter (JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:60)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter (ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter (TransactionCleanupFilter.java:48)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter (ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle (ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle (SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle (SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle (ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle (WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle (AppVersionHandlerMap.java:257)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle (HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle (Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest (HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete (HttpConnection.java:923)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable (RpcRequestParser.java:76)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle (HttpConnection.java:404)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest (JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:146)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchServletRequest (JavaRuntime.java:680)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchRequest (JavaRuntime.java:642)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run (JavaRuntime.java:612)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext (TraceContext.java:454)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run (TraceContext.java:461)
at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext (CurrentContext.java:297)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref (TraceContext.java:320)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext (TraceContext.java:312)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run (TraceContext.java:458)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run (ThreadGroupPool.java:274)
at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:745)
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Is this reproducible in the dev server environment? Can you show the contents of WEB-INF/lib in your deployment?